# Randomising use of Boomerang.js

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there a good reason why I shouldn't do this with [boomerang](http://yahoo.github.com/boomerang/doc/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (Math.random() < 0.005) {//one time in 200
            document.write(
                '<scr' + 'ipt src="/scripts/boomerang.js" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>' +
                    '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">BOOMR.init({'+
                        'user_ip: "'+ '<%= Request.UserHostAddress %>' +'",'+
                        'site_domain: "' + '<%= //TODO from config%>' + '",' +
                        'beacon_url: "/Handlers/Boomerang.ashx",'+
                        'BW: {base_url: "/Resources/images/Boomerang/"}'
                    +'});</scr' + 'ipt>'
            );
        }
        else if (Math.random() < 0.1) {//one time in ten
            document.write(
                '<scr' + 'ipt src="/scripts/boomerang.js" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>' +
                    '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">BOOMR.init({'+
                        'user_ip: "'+ '<%= Request.UserHostAddress %>' +'",'+
                        'site_domain: "' + '<%= //TODO from config%>' + '",' +
                        'beacon_url: "/Handlers/Boomerang.ashx",'+
                        'BW : { enabled : false }'+
                    '});</scr' + 'ipt>'
            );
        }
</script>
```

Will that invalidate the timings returned?

We are not too concerned about getting results using the multi-page method: we are content to only receive results from the timing api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just include boomerang on all pages, and only modify the call to init based on your sampling rate?  Something like this:

```
<script src="/scripts/boomerang.js"></script>
<script>
    var rand=Math.random(), test="";
    if(rand < 0.05) {     // one time in 200
        test="BW";
    }
    else if(rand < 0.1) { // 19 times in 200
        test="NOBW";
    }
    if(test) {
        BOOMR.addVar({
            test: test
        }).init({
            user_ip: "<%= Request.UserHostAddress %>",
            site_domain: "<%= //TODO from config%>",
            beacon_url: "/Handlers/Boomerang.ashx",
            BW: {
                base_url: (test == "BW" ? "/Resources/images/Boomerang/" : ""),
                enabled:  (test == "NOBW" ? false : true)
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The main difference between this script and your version is the addition of `addVar({ test: test })` which tells your beacon collector which version was used.  You might also want to pass in the value of `rand` if it helps with debugging.

I've measured the time it takes to load up boomerang for millions of users around the world from a single linode box, and the median load time is 68ms (we have the script cached for 7 days by the browser).  We also load the script asynchronously though, so that's something you may want to consider if you find boomerang itself affecting page load time.

Comment: Thanks, I have used this as leverage to get the requirement changed, and will be doing as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ask on [@bluesmoon](https://twitter.com/#!/bluesmoon) what the best way of randomising it is... sure he won't bite ;-)

Comment: I think he might have the horrors, but I have asked him to look at this question.